# Looping sprite sheet animations with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, loops

i've been having a problem with looping sprite sheet animations which are playing after one another. Maybe someone might know what to do. http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/yabpxo

```
setTimeout(function() {
$(".kambarys2").css('display', 'block');
}, 3100);   
setTimeout(function() {
$(".kambarys3").css('display', 'block');
}, 6100);

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kambarys"></div>
<div class="kambarys2"></div>
<div class="kambarys3"></div>


body {
background-color: #69e4c3;
}
.kambarys {
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/pra08AS.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 380px;
height: 372px;
top: 100px;
left: 40%;
animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
}
@keyframes convejor {
from {
 background-position: 0px;
}
to {
background-position: -28880px;
}
}
.kambarys2 {
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/TFvZvWz.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
width: 380px;
height: 372px;
top: 108px;
left: 40%;
animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
display: none;
}
.kambarys3 {
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/F6bNA00.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
width: 380px;
height: 372px;
top: 108px;
left: 40%;
animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
display: none;
```

maybe there is something wrong with the existing jquery

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, messed up my codepen link, updated it now... the problem is that I need to loop the spritesheets, as in the first one plays, then the next one, and the third one, and then repeat the process. I just managed to make them play after each other, what need now is just to repeat the process...

Comment: Allcool, figured it out...